# Why am I getting error sometimes when I try to publish a Custom Open Graph Story?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Why am I getting this error sometimes when I try to call this command sometimes?

error:

```
code: 100
message: "(#100) Could not resolve object at URL 405930826276617."
type: "OAuthException"
```

command:

```
 FB.api(
   'me/myapp:pass_friend',
   'post',
   {
      level_number: levelNumber,
      person: {
        'og:title': title,
        'og:type': 'myapp:person',
        'og:image': imgUrl
    }
  },
  function (response) {
    if (response && !response.error) {
        console.log('[publishPassFriend] API response', response);
    } else {
        console.error('[publishPassFriend] API error', response);
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Is this still occurring for you and only happening intermittently? If so I would suggest filing a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Yes it is still occurring and only happening intermittently.